# WiFi Tethering (Hot Spot) with no outside internet

Tags: android, wifi, tethering

I have a project to create a system, utilizing tablets and an app that will reside on three separate tablets.  One of the tablets will be a main (or server) that will display the overall state of the app and the other two will allow a/an operator(s) to utilize functions.

I don't want any of the tablets to have mobile data or an outside internet connection, but want them to talk exclusively to each other.

Am I on the right track by utilizing the one as a hot spot and the other two connect to it?  Is that possible with mobile data disabled?

Answer (score 0):

I think bluetooth may be the the answer , take a look at this class it could be a great starting point :

https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com.example.android.bluetoothchat/BluetoothChatService.html